# Aligning the text of a TextField with its Trailing icon

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have an svg icon in my drawables folder from our designer, and I'm trying to figure out a way to align the trailing icon of the TextField with its text in a way that it will look the same on most devices. I'm trying to avoid fixed dp values but I can't find a built-in way to do this.

screen code:

```
        var customAmountTxt by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue()) }
        TextField(
            value = customAmountTxt,
            onValueChange = {
                customAmountTxt = it
            },
            maxLines = 1,
            singleLine = true,
            leadingIcon = {
                Icon(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_euro),
                    contentDescription = stringResource(
                        R.string.euro_icon_desc
                    ),
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(
                        start = 16.dp,
                        end = 16.dp,
                        top = 12.dp,
                        bottom = 12.dp
                    )
                )
            },
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number,
                imeAction = ImeAction.Done
            ),
            keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onDone = {
                focusManager.clearFocus()
                keyboardController?.hide()
            }),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(6.dp),
            colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                backgroundColor = colorResource(id = R.color.white),
                textColor = colorResource(id = R.color.black),
                focusedIndicatorColor = colorResource(id = R.color.white),
                unfocusedIndicatorColor = colorResource(id = R.color.white),
                disabledIndicatorColor = colorResource(id = R.color.white),
                cursorColor = colorResource(id = R.color.black)
            ),
            textStyle = TextStyle(
                color = Color.Black,
                fontSize = 16.sp,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Start
            ),
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(50.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .shadow(8.dp, shape = RoundedCornerShape(6.dp))
        )
```

current output:

[image: output]